# Sufficient prerequisites for android application development

Tags: java, php, android, c++, xml

I tried to search for the basic skills required for starting to learn android application development and many suggested that you need to be familiar with **Java** , **c++** , **pearl** or **php script** , **xml** along with knowledge about usage of graphic resources.

My problem is I know nothing about above languages except for c++ which I've been learning for 2 years in my school.

Now what I want to know is, should I go ahead with learning android application development or is it waste of time to start without learning the other languages mentioned above ?

Comment: I suggest you learn java first... learning Android will become relatively easy once you learn Java..

Comment: My issue is , i can't afford to learn other languages due to approaching exams. But i am really wanting to learn android application development. So, can i go ahead or should i really force on learning java first and then start with development ?? In the latter case I'll have to wait for the exams to get over(which will take approximately 2 months).

Comment: Alas.. Some decisions are yours to make...

Comment: I will wait then , thank you for guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must learn java, or you end up using Android NDK (Simple Hello World apps will do), which may end up interfacing with Java later with difficult tasks.

XML is a must learn to create the interface of the application, but it is kind of simple using Eclipse as development platform (having Android-tool installed) drag and drop.

PHP, PEARL you can forget them for the time being unless you want to create a web server for you android apps.

Comment: Xml is not necessarily a must. A recommendation  maybe, but not a must. For example if he plans to use a third party library which relies on opengl to draw.

Answer (score 0):

First learn java, after that target to the android. Remember, everything has a way to learn, first thing should comes first. Don't try to take shortcuts, you'll get nothing from it. Java will help you to elaborate your android development experience.